# Is it possible to discard data errors in a Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I will have a lot of variables in my `Vue` instance modified via API calls. Their initial value is not important.

I was hoping there would be a way **not** to define them upon the instantiation of the vm but this does not work:

```js
vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {}
});
vm.number = 3
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ number }}
</div>
```

If I replace `data: {}` by `data: { number: null }` the code runs fine.

What I would like to avoid is to have a litany of such declarations - **is there a way not to declare the `data` variables upon instantiation?**

Comment: How about `data: { container: { number:null, ... } }`? I'm sure you could come up with a better name for `container` since you know the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) explain how reactivity works in Vue as follows:

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data
> option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them
> to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty.

...

> The getter/setters are invisible to the user, but under the hood they
> enable Vue to perform dependency-tracking and change-notification when
> properties are accessed or modified.

...

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> Object.observe), **Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.**

So basically in plain terms, in order for a data value to be reactive and thus be updated when your API call returns, the property must be present from the time of instantiation because **Vue cannot detect addions or deletions**.

That being said, you can sort of fake it as was suggested by @gskema by using a placeholder object and attaching your properties to that object. These changes will indeed be picked up by Vue.

So you could do:

```
data: {
  api: null
}
```

and then attach your api values to that `api` property when they are returned, and finally just reference all the data by `api.number` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I use components so the solution to have a "containerized" set of variables is what I will have done anyway - if there was not a way to avoid declaring the variables. Your answer makes it very clear that this is not possible.